# How can I Refactor This To Pass in the "Property to Use" in this Lambda to Make This Method Reusable?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, refactoring, linqkit

In my web page, there are multiple textboxes where users can enter complex queries.  A complex query can contain any of the following `Parameter`s:

1. `XX*` that matches everything *starting with* XX
2. `*XX` for everything *ending in* XX
3. `*XX*` for everything *containing* XX
4. `XX123-XX129` for everthing matching the *inclusive range* from XX123 to XX129
5. `XX444` for an exact individual value
6. ... any comma separated combination of any/all of the above

Implementing that is not my problem; my problem is implementing it for multiple values in a **reuseable** manner.

The sample below filters `Items` on the `Item.Value` property.

```cs
public static IQueryable<Item> WithMatchingItemValues(this IQueryable<Item> items,
    IEnumerable<Parameter> itemValues)
{
    var parameters = (itemValues ?? Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>()).ToList();
    if (parameters.IsEmpty()) return items;

    var (wildCards, exactMatches) = parameters.SplitOnWildCards();

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Item>(); // https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit

    wildCards.ForEach(wc =>
    {
        switch (wc)
        {
            case WildCardStartsWith startsWith:
                predicate = predicate.Or(s => s.Value.ToUpper().StartsWith(startsWith.ToString()));
                break;
            case WildCardContains contains:
                predicate = predicate.Or(s => s.Value.ToUpper().Contains(contains.ToString()));
                break;
            case WildCardEndsWith endsWith:
                predicate = predicate.Or(s => s.Value.ToUpper().EndsWith(endsWith.ToString()));
                break;
        }
    });

    if (exactMatches.Any())
        predicate = predicate.Or(s => exactMatches.Select(p => p.Value).Contains(s.Value.ToUpper()));

    return items.AsExpandableEFCore().Where(predicate);
}
```

How can I refactor this so I can "pass in" the `Item.Value` to the method, so I can also pass in `Item.PartNumber` or `Item.Foo` without having to duplicate all this code for every property I want to filter?  I can't just pass in `Item.Value`... that's just a string, and won't work in the lambda statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your method to take an `ExpressionLambda` that represents the field reference:

```
public static IQueryable<Item> WithMatchingItemValues(this IQueryable<Item> items,
    IEnumerable<Parameter> itemValues,
    Expression<Func<Item,string>> field)
```

Then in the code that needs to refer to the field, use LINQKit's `Invoke` method:

```
case WildCardStartsWith startsWith:
    predicate = predicate.Or(s => field.Invoke(s).ToUpper().StartsWith(startsWith.ToString()));
```

Finally, use LINQKit's `Expand` method to inline expand the `field` references, or use `AsExpandable` as you have on the data source:

```
if (exactMatches.Any())
    predicate = predicate.Or(s => exactMatches.Select(p => p.Value).Contains(field.Invoke(s).ToUpper()));

return items.AsExpandableEFCore().Where(predicate);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on that last line's `predicate.Expand()` method call: Cannot convert from `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyProj.Data.Models.Item, bool>>` ... where'd I go wrong here...

Comment: @ScottBaker Not sure - since you have `AsExpandable` you don't need `Expand()` so I removed it from my answer...